# Ringbuffer for a microcontroller

Tags: c, stm32, firmware

Here is a scenario I'm facing right now, I have an interrupt(thread) UART that is reading  to a ringbuffer from the values that I get from the serial port, and also writing the values from the serial port to the ring buffer.
I have a main loop that access that ringbuffer for reading the values from it, while writing an AT Command, and also writing to the ring buffer those AT Commands.
Do I need the ringbuffer to be lock free or surround the shared data with a semaphore or a mutex ? I don't have an OS for getting a mutex or semaphore working.
I have read alot about the subject and it seems I need a lock free ringbuffer. On ARM I would use a compare and swap instruction. The ringbuffer is implemented as an array so I wouldn't run into ABA problem

Declaration of buffers:

```
#define MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT 5

#define UART_BUFSIZE 512
char buffers[2][MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT][UART_BUFSIZE];

char* writeBuffers[MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT];
char* readBuffers[MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT];
volatile int readPos[MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT] = { 0 };
volatile int writePos[MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT] = { 0 };
here is the interrupt code

void USART_IRQHandler(char Channel, USART_TypeDef *USARTx)
{
    volatile unsigned int IIR;
    int c = 0;
    IIR = USARTx->SR;
    if (IIR & USART_FLAG_RXNE)
    {                  // read interrupt
      USARTx->SR &= ~USART_FLAG_RXNE;             // clear interrupt

        c = USART_ReceiveData(USARTx);
        writeBuffers[Channel][writePos[Channel]] = c;
    writePos[Channel]++;
        if(writePos[Channel]>=UART_BUFSIZE) writePos[Channel]=0;

    }

    if (IIR & USART_FLAG_TXE)
    {
      USARTx->SR &= ~USART_FLAG_TXE;              // clear interrupt
    }
}
code for initializing and swapping the buffers:

void initializeBuffers(void) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CHANNEL_COUNT; ++i)
    {
        writeBuffers[i] = buffers[0][i];
        readBuffers[i] = buffers[1][i];
    }
}

void swapBuffers(int channel) {
  int i;
  char * buf = writeBuffers[channel];
    __disable_irq();
  writeBuffers[channel] = readBuffers[channel];
  readBuffers[channel] = buf;
  if ( readPos[channel] == UART_BUFSIZE)
           readPos[channel] = 0;
    
  for (i =0; i < UART_BUFSIZE; i++)
  {
    buf[i] = 0;
  }
    __enable_irq();
}
```

here I use this function to get a char from a specific channel and from a specific UART

```
int GetCharUART (char Channel)
{
 int c =  readBuffers[Channel][readPos[Channel]++];

    
  if (c == 0 || readPos[Channel] == UART_BUFSIZE)
  {
    swapBuffers(Channel); // Make this clear your read buffer.
    return EMPTY;
  }
  return c; // Note, your code that calls this should handle the case where c == 0
}
```

usage of GetCharUart

```
PutStringUART(UART_GSM, "AT");
PutStringUART(UART_GSM, pCommand);
PutCharUART(UART_GSM, '\r');
count = 0;
timer_100ms = 0;
while (timer_100ms <= timeout)
{
    zeichen = GetCharUART(UART_GSM);
}
```

Comment: I think some code is needed to clarify the operations on the buffer, a bit, and also list more clearly the producers and consumers. It sounds the UART ISR can produce stuff, and that the main thread does both produce/consume, which seems imbalanced and confusing. Perhaps you need two ring buffers, each going in a single direction between interrupt and main code?

Comment: @unwind I haved some code.

Comment: I gave you a link yesterday to a post explaining why you need a semaphore and how to implement it in the most simple manner on a bare metal MCU. What happened to that? Here's the link again, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/409570/6102, it explains the use of volatile and how to use a semaphore in the same answer. Which are two unrelated issues.

Comment: @Lundin The post was deleted by the moderators.

Comment: AhmedSaleh, Tip: rather than 5 array objects, consider using an array of 1  `struct` that has  5 members.

Comment: By the way, since you tagged this STM32... why on earth aren't you using DMA for this? It will make most of your problems go away (though setting up DMA is usually "exciting" in itself).

Comment: @Lundin woudn't a DMA on stm32 needs too synchronization ?

Comment: AhmedSaleh `GetCharUART()` simple is not safe as the interrupt handler may be called during critical portions,

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You're right. so I would disable/enable interrupt in that function ```GetCharUART()``` or where exactly ? also how about writing a lock free buffer

Comment: Yes all DMA needs some manner of synchronization too, but it saves you from a lot of real-time issues. Implementing UART drivers with Rx interrupts is just painful, I've written far too many over the years to do so yet again if DMA is an option.

Comment: AhmedSaleh, the buffers do not need locking so much.  It is the pointer/index to the buffer that need locking before examining/changing.  [Locking thought](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464202/ringbuffer-for-a-microcontroller?noredirect=1#comment122779953_69464332).  Also the enable/disable/test/restore interrupt is very CPU specific.  I am not well versed in STM32.

Comment: @Lundin I'm using that firmware for 60k devices out there. If I use DMA and result in issues, that would mess up with those devices. So I wanna keep things simple at first. Anyway as you are an embedded expert, how would a lock free buffer be done on STM32, I have not found any implementation out there.

Comment: "Lock free" is kind of a myth, it can only be achieved if you have atomic access. Which means C11 `_Atomic` or inline asm. I usually implement ring buffers with a pointer and mask to the UART interrupt instead, and temporarily disable it during access. This assumes that you can disable, access and enable faster than a full byte cycle on the UART, or you will lose data. So given lets say 115.2kbps 8-n-1, your code needs to finish within 8.68us * 10 = 86.8us. Give or take some interrupt latency. This shouldn't be any trouble on a Cortex M unless you run some low power system clock.

Comment: If you have other "hard" real-time things in the same system, that's another story though.

Comment: @Lundin yes it's a hard real time system, how about compare and swap, how would one use it for a lock free ringbuffer ? I think Keil doesn't support C11 with _Atomic

Comment: I guess you could write it in inline asm, where atomicity is usually not a problem. The key is that the calling code in the background program must never be allowed to partially access a shared variable. Also as someone said, use different buffers for rx and tx - takes more memory but saves you from a whole lot of complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need synchronization between interrupt handlers and the "main-thread", so yes a sort of mutex is needed. The usual method without OS, is to just disable interrupts before "entering the critical section" and re-enable afterwards. That ensures the critical section is "atomic" (i.e. no interrupts fire in the meantime).

> On ARM I would use a compare and swap instruction

What compiler are you using?

GCC and Clang has intrinsics for atomic compare-and-swap.

See e.g.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html

https://llvm.org/docs/Atomics.html

C11 supports it via `<stdatomic.h>` I believe: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange

Comment: Actually I know about disabling/enabling the interrupt. but the problem is I'm waiting for some interrupts from other devices at the same time. so disabling/enable interrupts are not beneficial in my case. I'm using Keil uVision.

Comment: You could use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm 
as a poor-man's mutual exclusion if there are no good intrinsics with Keil (I haven't used it)

Comment: Morten, UV for "need synchronization ".   Peterson algorithm is broke given shared `int turn;` is not `volatile` and P1 could run between `turn = 1;` and `while (flag[1] == true && turn == 1)`.

Comment: Morton, rather than "disable interrupts before ... re-enable afterwards.", I found "record interrupt state, disable  ... re-store afterwards." more  useful.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I agree it's more useful to save state and reenable afterwards, but then we quickly get into implementation details, so I was talking in general terms. I agree with you w.r.t. Peterson's: You have to be careful when implementing sync-primitives. I did not mean for the wiki-article to provide the implementation, just explain the concept :)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, I would recommend splitting the ring buffer into a reading and a writing buffer (can be a ring buffer).

When you use interrupts, you have concurrency, which means that you need to protect shared data (i.e., your buffers). This is often done by mutexes or semaphores. However, they are only available on OSs or RTOSs.

So the most common thing to do is to *temporarily* serialise your concurrent elements. This can be done by disabling the UART interrupt. More precisely, you need to deactivate all interrupts, which can trigger code that uses the shared resource.

Comment: Actually I know about disabling/enabling the interrupt. but the problem is I'm waiting for some interrupts from other devices at the same time. so disabling/enable interrupts are not beneficial in my case.

Comment: you can just disable the UART interrupt.
When disabling/enabling interrupts, you do that only to write into a shared variable, so it would take only a few instructions. So, unless you are in a hard hard real-time environment, it is commonly not a problem to quickly deactivate it and activate it again